# Google Big Query SQL - Get Most Recent Column Value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Google Big Query Table that has an `email` column in it. Basically each rows shows a state the user with that email address existed in. What I want to do is query the table to get a result showing the most recent row per email address. I've tried all sorts of `GROUP BY`'s, `JOIN`ing the table against itself and the usual fun stuff that I would use in MySQL, but I keep getting duplicate emails returned if the entire row isn't a match.

Any help is much appreciated!

Sample Data

```
user_email     | user_first_name | user_last_name | time      | is_deleted
test@test.com  | Joe             | John           | 123456790 |  1
test@test.com  | Joe             | John           | 123456789 |  0
test2@test.com | Jill            | John           | 123456789 |  0
```

So if sampling that data I would want to return:

```
user_email     | user_first_name | user_last_name | time      | is_deleted
test@test.com  | Joe             | John           | 123456790 |  1
test2@test.com | Jill            | John           | 123456789 |  0
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT user_email, user_first_name, user_last_name, time, is_deleted 
FROM (
 SELECT user_email, user_first_name, user_last_name, time, is_deleted
      , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY user_email ORDER BY time DESC) rank
 FROM table
)
WHERE rank=1
```

Comment: How would you do the same thing if your table contains nested and repeated fields ?

Comment: If you can provide a sample table with nested and repeated fields, I'll do my best to provide an answer. Please start a new question too!

Comment: Ok, I've created a new question that you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150732/get-most-recent-column-value-with-nested-and-repeated-fields

Answer (score 3):

There is a potential shortcoming of the use of `RANK()` over the [alternative numbering function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions) `ROW_NUMBER()`. The accepted answer does provide the desired solution, except in the event in a tie in the order by clause, were duplicate records are again returned:

```
with minimal_reproducible as (
select 'test@test.com' as user_email, 'Joe' as user_first_name, 'John' as user_last_name, 123456789 as time, 1 is_deleted
union all
select 'test@test.com', 'Joe', 'John', 123456789, 0
union all
select 'test2@test.com', 'Jill', 'John', 123456789, 0
)

select user_email, user_first_name, user_last_name, time, is_deleted from (
    select *, 
    rank() over (partition by user_email order by time desc) as rank
    from minimal_reproducible) inner_table 
where rank = 1;
```

A better solution therefore is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` in the place of `RANK()` to ensure (albeit arbitrarily) unique `user_email` come what may:

```
with minimal_reproducible as (
select 'test@test.com' as user_email, 'Joe' as user_first_name, 'John' as user_last_name, 123456789 as time, 1 is_deleted
union all
select 'test@test.com', 'Joe', 'John', 123456789, 0
union all
select 'test2@test.com', 'Jill', 'John', 123456789, 0
)

select user_email, user_first_name, user_last_name, time, is_deleted from (
    select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by user_email order by time desc) as row_number
    from minimal_reproducible) inner_table 
where row_number = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

```
SELECT l.* FROM [mytable.list] l JOIN (
    SELECT user_email, MAX(time) as time FROM [mytable.list] GROUP EACH BY user_email
) j ON j.user_email = l.user_email WHERE j.time = l.time;
```

Comment: Good! Take a look at using OVER() functions too, look at the alternative answer.

Comment: Thanks @FelipeHoffa, What is the benefit and/or contrast of using your solution?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I agree, add some explaining with your solution please.