# How can I avoid and/or clean duplicated row in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How should I import data in BigQuery on a daily basis when I have potential duplicated row ?

Here is a bit of context. I'm updating data on a daily basis from a spreadsheet to BigQuery. I'm using Google App Script with a simple WRITE_APPEND method.

Sometimes I'm importing data I've already imported the day before. So I'm wondering how I can avoid this ?

Can I build a sql query in order to clean my table from duplicate row every day ? Or is this possible to detect duplicate even before importing them (with some specific command in my job definition for example...) ?

thanks !

Comment: Do you have a unique column such as an ID or insertion timestamp? You may be able to find past answers about removing duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Step 1**: Have a sheet with data to be imported

[image]

- **Step 2**: Set up your spreadsheet as a federated data source in BigQuery.

[image]

- **Step 3**: Use DML to load data into an existing table

(requires #standardSql)

```
#standardSQL
INSERT INTO `fh-bigquery.tt.test_import_native` (id, data)
SELECT *
FROM `fh-bigquery.tt.test_import_sheet` 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id 
  FROM `fh-bigquery.tt.test_import_native`
)
```

`WHERE id NOT IN (...)` ensures that only rows with new ids are loaded into the table.

Comment: Note, that it is still possible to get duplicates in the table with this method, if more than one INSERT INTO statement runs at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the answer provided by Felipe Hoffa is the most effective way to avoid duplicate rows since Bigquery do not normalize data when loading data. The reason is that Bigquery performs best with denormalized data [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_denormalized_nested_and_repeated_data). To better understand it, I’d recommend you to have a look in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585118/avoid-duplicates-in-bigquery).

I also would like to suggest using SQL aggregate or analytic function to clean the duplicate rows in a Bigquery table, as Felipe Hoffa's or Jordan Tigani's answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675521/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-bigquery-table).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Felipe answer is more straightforward but yours is also very valuable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large-size partitioned table, and only want to remove duplicates in a given range without scanning through (cost-saving) and replacing the whole table.

use the MERGE SQL below:

```
-- WARNING: back up the table before this operation
-- FOR large size timestamp partitioned table 
-- -------------------------------------------
-- -- To de-duplicate rows of a given range of a partition table, using surrage_key as unique id
-- -------------------------------------------

DECLARE dt_start DEFAULT TIMESTAMP("2019-09-17T00:00:00", "America/Los_Angeles") ;
DECLARE dt_end DEFAULT TIMESTAMP("2019-09-22T00:00:00", "America/Los_Angeles");

MERGE INTO `your_project`.`data_set`.`the_table` AS INTERNAL_DEST
USING (
  SELECT k.*
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(original_data LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] k 
    FROM `your_project`.`data_set`.`the_table` AS original_data
    WHERE stamp BETWEEN dt_start AND dt_end
    GROUP BY surrogate_key
  )

) AS INTERNAL_SOURCE
ON FALSE

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
  AND INTERNAL_DEST.stamp BETWEEN dt_start AND dt_end -- remove all data in partiion range
    THEN DELETE

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ROW
```

credit: https://gist.github.com/hui-zheng/f7e972bcbe9cde0c6cb6318f7270b67a